# How should i test controller with jbuilder views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, jbuilder

this is my controller

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController 
    def show 
        @news = News.find_by id: params[:id]
    end
 end
```

this is views

```
json.extract! @news ,:id, :title , :content , :created_at , :updated_at
json.image @news.images do |image| 
    json.url url_for(image)
  end
```

what is right way of testing this controller and views. I'am new into testing so i'am little bit frustrated with this

Comment: You should be using `@news = News.find(params[:id])`. `find_by` will just return nil if an invalid id was passed and then your view will blow up. Do not use `find_by` unless getting nil is actually acceptable - which is pretty rare.

Answer (score -1):

You can verify the status and the json result you are expecting

```
it "should have a 200 code" do
  get :show, params: { id: 1 }, format: :json
  expect(response.status).to eq 200
  expect(response.body).to eq expected_json
end
```

Refer [this](https://rubyinrails.com/2019/04/11/rails-test-jbuilder-json-response-with-rspec/) article for more info